# How to continue in computation process in Jupyter notebook on different device

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub, binderhub

**Background info:**
I have a situation when I do the computation on some device (let's say device A). After some time I would like to transfer to other device (let's say mobile device B) and continue in the same computational process as I started on device A.

**Problem:**
When I open the notebook on device B there is a problem with the cell presently running. There is no continuous output visible on device B (let's say every 5 seconds there should be some checkpoint visible). It is like the cell is not even running. It's marked ([ ]) instead of ([*]). This way I have no idea when the computation will stop or how the output looks like on device B.

**My effort:**
What I have tried so far is to reconnect to a kernel on device B with no results. Also I can see that on device B the kernel is not active which in my opinion means that I have to somehow (re)connect to the running kernel on device A. There is an option to switch kernels with possibility to "choose kernel from other session" (I assume this is the solution). But I cannot find a way to connect to a kernel from session on device A.

**Bonus info:**
I use Binderhub, not pure Jupyter notebooks

Comment: is binderhub running on an external service like a cloud provider? your "bonus info" line is where all of the important detail needs to be - this question is very setup specific :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yes it does run on Kubernetes cluster. Also meanwhile I was looking into the problem and I found out that whenever I save notebook on device A (ctrl+s), after refresh on device B the output shows. But I don't think that increase of autosave frequency is the right solution.

Comment: based on your above comment. do you only want to see the results on device B, or do you want to switch to use the computation power on device B. the later one seems to be hard to implement. if you only want to check the running output update on device B, then as you just said, saving it then you see the output. you could also maybe write the output to external log file, then you can check it without saving the notebook file.

Comment: I thought that the functionality you mentioned with switching the computation power to device B is somehow present in Jupyter by default. That is in fact what I was aiming at at first but your approach with printing the output into a file is a nice workaround which will suffice for my use case. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I followed an idea by [@Rock](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16317905/rock) and came up with a workaround to **transfer all the output to log file**. This way I got a real time output on device B which was sufficient to my use case.